# Loading a modified pretrained model using strict=False in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I want to use a pretrained model as the encoder part in my model. You can find a version of my model:

```
class MyClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=False):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.encoder=S3D_featureExtractor_multi_output()
        if pretrained:

        weight_dict=torch.load(os.path.join('models','weights.pt'))

        model_dict=self.encoder.state_dict()
        
        list_weight_dict=list(weight_dict.items())
        list_model_dict=list(model_dict.items())
        
        for i in range(len(list_model_dict)):
            assert list_model_dict[i][1].shape==list_weight_dict[i][1].shape
            model_dict[list_model_dict[i][0]].copy_(weight_dict[list_weight_dict[i][0]])
        
        for i in range(len(list_model_dict)):
            assert torch.all(torch.eq(model_dict[list_model_dict[i][0]],weight_dict[list_weight_dict[i][0]].to('cpu')))
        print('Loading finished!')
                
def forward(self, x):
    
    a, b = self.encoder(x)
    return a, b
```

Because I modified some parts of the code of this pretrained model, based on [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-delete-some-layers-in-pretrained-model/122607/2?u=tm4) I need to apply `strict=False` to avoid facing error, but based on the scenario that I load the pretrained weights, I cannot find a place in the code to apply strict=False. How can I apply that or how can I change the scenario of loading the pretrained model taht makes it possible to apply `strict=False`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strict = False` is to specify when you use `load_state_dict()` method. `state_dict` are just Python dictionaries that helps you save and load model weights.
(for more details, see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/what_is_state_dict.html)

If you use `strict=False` in `load_state_dict`, you inform PyTorch that the target model and the original model are not identical, so it just initialises the weights of layers which are present in both and ignores the rest.
(see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=load_state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict)

So, you will need to specify the strict argument when you load the pretrained model weights. `load_state_dict` can be called at this step.
If the model for which weights must be loaded is `self.encoder`
and if `state_dict` can be retrieved from the model you just loaded, you can just do this

```
loaded_weights = torch.load(os.path.join('models','weights.pt'))
self.encoder.load_state_dict(loaded_weights, strict=False)
```

for more details and a tutorial, see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Based on your answer is it needed or possible to have assertion phrases of the code or it is not? If yes, can you add your answer inside the MyClass to make it possible to see the final modified code?

Comment: If i have to rewrite your code, i'll make it this way. 
I will replace ` weight_dict=torch.load(os.path.join('models','weights.pt'))` by my last 2 proposed line of code. But i cannot be sure since i did not run it on my machine...

Comment: Thanks, but I get a little confused because I cannot find strict=false in your last comment and there is a difference in comparison to the answer. Where should I put your answer inside of your last comment?

Comment: loaded_weights = torch.load(os.path.join('models','weights.pt'))
self.encoder.load_state_dict(loaded_weights, strict=False)

Comment: Is there a similar approach in TensorFlow as well?